# Just how much light does the Eg-S Focusing Screen reduce?

Tags: focusing-screen

I have a couple of manual focus lenses that I like to use with a Canon 5Dmk2. In an effort to make this task a bit easier, I'm considering a purchase of the Canon Super Precision Matte Eg-S Interchangeable Focusing Screen.

The specs sheet says to use this with lenses at f/2.8 or faster, lest the viewfinder get "very dim".

I also happen to shoot with some slow lenses, like the 400mm f/5.6.

Does anyone have any personal experience using this screen with slower lenses? Is the viewfinder completely junk or passable in bright light?

Thanks,

Comment: Related, especially the first answer which touches on slow lenses being quite dark with focusing screens: [Why don't DSLRs come equipped with "classic" focusing screens (split prism, etc)?](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/11621)

Comment: Also related: [How much light is lost through a typical matte focusing screen?](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/64404)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that f/4 lens can get a bit too dark using Canon Eg-S screen. [On this forum, one user said](http://dpreview.com/forums/thread/2523100):

> I tried 24-105 f/4L and for indoor uses or outdoors at evening I believe VF is too dark. It's still usable but the VF is really much darker than with standard focusing screen

Perhaps, better question would be: `I have f/5.6 manual lens and would like to get better focusing screen for my Canon 5D II`

Split-prism focusing screen might be a good option. Unfortunately, Canon doesn't make one for 5D mkII. From [their PDF on screens](https://www.learn.usa.canon.com/app/pdfs/quickguides/CDLC_FocusingScreens_QuickGuide.pdf):

[image]

However, there is a Taiwan [company that seems to be selling split-image screens](https://www.focusingscreen.com/index.php?cPath=21_98&osCsid=e2b6d8d1b1455a5200dff52650734d0b) for Canon 5D mkII (and many other cameras), for ~$85 USD:

[image]

PS: on the other hand, I wonder how much precision you need to focus f/5.6 lens, even a longer one. Depth of field will be larger, so I guess there is less pressure to focus precisely, unlike with paper-thin DoF of f/2.8 tele and f/1.2-f/1.8 normal lenses.

Comment: Really blows my mind that there isn't more overlap in focusing screens between bodies. Seems like a part that would be easier and cheaper to use holding over the design between as many bodies as possible.

Comment: @corey my guess is that interchangeable focussing screens are just a rudiment of the "film days". Hence there is no coherent strategy to develop and produce them.